# Redirect to the root route using zuul

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, ribbon, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul

I have configured zuul using below configuration

```
eureka.client.service-url.default-zone=http://localhost:8761/eureka
spring.application.name=zuul-api-gateway-server
server.port=8765   
ribbon.ReadTimeout=60000
```

and my another service name is xyz-ui, when i am consuming the web service from xyz-ui then i am putting the url like http://localhost:8765/xyz-ui/abc.

I want to invoke the http://localhost:8765/abc (without service name).

Please suggest the configuration for this.

Comment: You have to ask more specific question or post a job ad ;-)

Comment: @MaciejWalkowiak Already asked ;).